# Закрыть доступ к локальному серверу

Tags: linux, ubuntu, веб-сервер, lamp

На ubuntu запустил сервер lamp, создал сайт, но теперь любой компьютер, подключенный к локальной сети, имеет возможность просмотреть этот сайт. Как разрешить доступ к этому сайту ТОЛЬКО с моего компьютера?

Comment: прописать запреты в .htaccess или закрыть доступ фаерволом, т.е. iptables

Comment: @Mike  пытался сделать так: sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP, но после ввода этой команды сайт вообще отказывался открываться как на текущем, так и на других пк.

Comment: Логично. Вы же запретили всем доступ. Перед этой строкой следовало добавить явное разрешение для того ip, с которого можно заходить (-s IP -j ACCEPT).

Comment: а ечли нужен доступ только с __локальной машины__, то лучше настроить веб-сервер, чтобы он биндиться только на локалхост...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Ubuntu есть утилита называемая `ufw` упрощающая работу с iptables. Все установленные посредством `ufw` правила фильтрации будут применяться как к ipv4 так и к ipv6, и будут автоматически применятся при загрузке системы.

Чтоб включить фильтрацию сетевой активности (применить правила фильтрации по умолчанию которые придумали в Canonical) нужно выполнить:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

После этого, посредством iptables, к netfilter применятся правила которые будут сбрасывать входящие соединения и логировать попытки их установления в журнал. Исходящие соединения не пострадают.

Посмотреть статус (настройки):

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

Выключить (удалить правила фильтрации):

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Пример добавления и удаления специального правила позволяющего выполнить входящее соединение через конкретный порт:

```
sudo ufw allow 22
sudo ufw delete allow 22
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Насколько я понял, после выполнения команды sudo ufw enable все порты автоматически закрываются, и для их открытия нужно прописать sudo ufw allow НОМЕР_ПОРТА, верно? Если да, то возникает вопрос, зачем существует команда sudo ufw deny НОМЕР_ПОРТА, ведь порты по умолчанию закрываются?

Comment: Нет, не всё порты закрываются. После включения файрвола некоторые предопределённые порты остаются открытыми. В частности 22 и 80, а также некоторые другие, но если установлены программы их использующие. Помимо этого, команда на закрытие порта нужна, чтобы отменить симметричную ей команду открытия.

Answer (score 2):

Есть ещё один возможный способ ограничить доступ к серверу только локальными пользователями компьютера. Можно отредактировать файл `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, указав там локальный IP-адрес.

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Нужно добавить часть, выделенную курсивом, и закомментировать строчки, относящиеся к 443 порту.

После правки конфигурации не забудьте перезагрузить веб-сервер.

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```